# How to suppress unicode characters in QString or convert to latin1

Tags: qt, unicode, firebird, qstring, latin

Trying to insert some data from CSV to Firebird table in Qt. DB is in ASCII. When inserting some strings with non-ascii symbols get error:

> Cannot transliterate character between character sets

Setting `QSqlDatabase::setConnectOptions("ISC_DPB_LC_CTYPE=UTF8;")` and converting column to UTF8 (`CHARACTER SET UTF8`) does not help - same error. Trying to suppress unicode characters with no luck as well:

```
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("latin1");
    QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(str);
    str = QString(encodedString);
```

`QString::toLatin1 ()` does not suppress characters as well. What solution could be here?

Comment: Strange, `ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <column> TYPE VARCHAR(x) CHARACTER SET UTF8` does not change column character set, remains ASCII.

Comment: `QString` is already in utf-16, your convertion will strip all non 7-bit ascii characters and it useless. What is your output data type from FireBird? Show code, how you fill your `str` first time.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me, what you want to achieve? You need to strip all non-ascii chars? Are you looking for http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1 ?

Comment: I have Qt 4, however it does not work - does not suppress characters, and `toAscii()` and `toLatin()` do not work as well.

Comment: Query:  `INSERT INTO RXNORM_INGREDIENTS (RXCUI, RXAUI, STR) VALUES ('151513', '2355753', 'CinaziГЁre')`
Database Text: arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation - Cannot transliterate character between character sets
Driver Text: Unable to execute query

Comment: I mean C++ code, not your query.

Comment: Nothing special, just reads line from CSV, splits it and then assigns str = columns[14], that it.

Comment: Why do you read them to `QString` but not to `QByteArray`? In what encoding is your CSV? Utf-8 / ascii / utf-16 / other?

Comment: How QByteArray may help me? `QString line = importFile.readLine();
          QStringList columns = line.split("|", QString::KeepEmptyParts);` Think most file is latin1 and some chars are > 127 or Unicode.

Comment: You should know exact encoding to parse your CSV. And `readLine` returns `QByteArray`, not `QString` - this is your first mistake.

Comment: If I know encoding and read to byte array what this changes?

Comment: Ok, what encoding and what chars do you want to strip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code should do what you need:

```
QString h("Honkäüö?ß#asdfe");

unsigned char * data = (unsigned char*)h.data();

QString result;

for(int i = 0; h.size()*2; i+=2) {
   if(data[i] > 127) {
     result.append("?");
  } else {
     result.append(QChar(data[i]));
  }
}
```

Here is another, more robust, version:

```
QString h("Honkäüö?ß#asdfe");
QString result;

for(int i = 0; i < h.size(); ++i) {
   QChar qc = h.at(i);
   unsigned char c = *(unsigned char*)(&qc);
   if(c >= 127) {
     result.append("?");
   } else if (QChar(c).isPrint()) {
     result.append(QChar(c));
   }
}
```

`QString result` is just used to show what is extracted. You could copy the `data[i]` in a `char` array or a append to a `QByteArray`.

`result` is `Honk?????????#asdfe`

This works well for 16bit characters. 32bit characters result in additional '?'s or other characters.

Comment: good idea, will try if not find better way. Will replace chars > 127 with ? or smth like this. Good to replace chars with German umlaut 'Ä' for example to smth meaningful like 'A'.

Comment: You shoud not cast utf-16 data to 8-bit, because utf-16 chars may be with variable length.

Comment: True, I accounted for that fact in my last sentence.

Comment: @SaZ it is not a risk, doesn't render this approach useless and surely doesn't justify a down vote.

Comment: Seems above answer is the only way for now: Firebird does not allow to change column/table/DB codepage, only for newer created data.

Answer (score 0):

This code extract any unicode (emojis) from qstring (16 or 32 bits) and toReturn contain only characters from ASCII table ( unicode value less than 256 )

```
QString cleanQString(QString toClean) {

    QString toReturn="";

    for(int i=0;i<toClean.size();i++){
        if(toClean.at(i).unicode()<256){
            toReturn.append(toClean.at(i));
        }
    }

    return toReturn;


}
```